# VS2015: Can't build, missing DNX files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dnx

I am trying to compile my colleague's work on my pc. It seems there is a mismatching version of something somewhere, but I can't work out what.

When I attempt to build I am told the following files are missing:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets
```

If I try to cheekily move these missing files across to my computer I get different errors:

```
The GetRuntimeToolingPath task could not be loaded from the assembly
```

I didn't expect that moving the files across idea would work, because this is hardly a full install of whats missing. But what am I missing?

Comment: please check your visual studio version and Web Development Tools component are accordance with your colleague's. Or you can try to install the install required (or the latest) version of DNX using DNVM: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2016/01/14/getting-to-the-crux-of-dnvm-dnu-and-dnx-in-asp-net-5/